# wp-settings error because of dp.php

Tags: plugins

My website was infected with some malware and I used Wordfence to fix them. I replaced some files and deleted infected files, or restored them.

No in Update screen, I'm getting following errors:

```
/public_html/support/wp-admin/js/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/wp-settings.php on line 33

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/public_html/support/wp-admin/js/db.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php55/pear') in /public_html/wp-settings.php on line 33
```

Also Wordpress Updates gives this error:

```
Headers already sent in /home/finedine/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 33.
This is not a good sign, it may just be a poorly written plugin but Headers should not have been sent at this point.
Check the code in the above mentioned file to fix this problem.
```

How can avoid these errors?

Comment: Well it's simply a `404` error. Check if the following file actually exists on your server, and the permissions are set correctly.

Comment: It is not existing, most probably I deleted it.

Comment: It is probably one of the lines that the malware added to your code, Because that file doesn't actually belong there. If your website is hacked, the best practice it to delete everything other than `wp-content` and `wp-config.php` file, and then restore a fresh copy of WordPress to you installation directory.

Comment: Waiting for update of Wordpress. Maybe re-installing fixes this problem